# combining ms access vba codes

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2007, code-snippets

Me and my colleague are developing an ms access based application. We are designing and coding different pages/forms in order to divide work. We plan to merge our work later. How can we do that without any problems like spoiling the design and macros? We are using Ms access 2007 for front end and sqlserver 2005 as the datasource.

---

I found an idea somewhere on bytes.com. I can import forms, reports, queries,data and tables that I want.I'm going to try this. However, it's just an idea.So, need to study this approach by trial and error techniques.

Comment: As far as I know you can export just about any object from one access file to another.... right click.... export. Is that really all you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The most important requirement is to complete the overall design before you start coding.  For example:

- All the forms must have the same style.  Help and error information must be provided in the same way on each form.  If a user can divide the forms into two sets, you have failed.
- The database design must be finished with a complete, written description of each table, its relationships and its attributes.
- The purpose and parameters for each major macro must be defined.  If macro A1 exists only to service macro A then A1 is not a major macro and only A's author need know of its details until coding is complete.
- Agreed a documentation style and detail level.  If the application needs enhancement in six or twelve months' time, you should be able to work on the others macros and forms as easily as on your own.
- If one of you thinks a change to the design is required after coding has started, this change must be documented, agreed with the other and the change specification added to the master specification.

Many years ago I lectured on (Electronic Data interchange (EDI).  With EDI, the specification is divided into two with one set of organisations providing applications for message senders and another set providing applications for message receivers.  I often used an example in my lectures to help my audience understand the importance of a complete, unambiguous specification.

I want two shapes, an E and a reverse-E, which I can fit together to create a 10 cm square.  I do not care what they are made of providing they fit together perfectly.

If I give this task to a single organisation, this specification will be enough.  One organisation might use cardboard, another metal, but I do not care.  But suppose I ask one organisation to create the E and another the reverse-E.  How detailed does my specification have to be if I am to get my 10 cm square?  I would suggest: material, thickness and dimensions of the E.  My audience would compete to suggest more and more obscure characteristics that had to match: density, colour, pattern, texture, etc, etc.

I was not always convinced my audience listened to the rest of my lecture because they were searching for a characteristic that would cap all the others.  No matter, I had got across my major point which was why EDI specifications were no mind-blowingly detailed.

Your situation will not be so difficult since you and your colleague are probably in the same room and can talk whenever you want.  But I hope this example helps you understand how easy is it for the interface between your two parts to be less than seamless if you do not agree the complete design at the beginning.  It's the little assumptions - I though you knew I was doing it that way - that will kill your application.

**New section**

OK, probably most of my earlier advice was inappropriate in your situation.

So you are trying to modify code you did not write in a language you do not know.  Good luck; you will need it.

I think scope is going to be your biggest problem.  Most modern languages have namespaces allowing you to give a variable or a routine as much or as little scope as you require.  VBA only has three levels.

A variable declared within a function or subroutine is automatically private to that function or subroutine.

A variable declared as `Private` within a module is invisible to functions and subroutines in other modules but is visible to any function or subroutine within the module.

A variable declared as `Public` within a module is visible to any function or subroutine within the project.

Anything declared within a form is private to that form.  If a form wishes to pass a value to an outside function or subroutine, it can do so by writing to a public variable or by passing it in a parameter to a public function or subroutine.

*Avoiding Naming Conflicts* within VBA Help gives useful advice.

Form and module names will have to be unique across the merged project.  You will not be able to avoid have constants, variables, functions and sub-routines which are visible to the other's functions and sub-routines.  *Avoiding Naming Conflicts* offers one approach.  An approach I have used successfully is to divide the application into sub-applications and, if necessary, sub-sub-applications and to assign a prefix to each.  If every public constant, variable, function and sub-routine name has the appropriate prefix you can simulate namespace type control.

Comment: @Pynner and Tony:There is an already existing ms access 2007 based application which requires some changes related to the UI which includes adding a subform to an existing form or creating some new forms.Since we(new to access) are working on different servers, we need to merge the changes to get the final application ready. The design of the UI and the database is not to be tampered with so everything is in sync. Also, there are around 14 changes in an application with around 60 forms and reports which means we need to be very careful while merging so that the existing forms are not affected.

Comment: @user1175126.  I hope my new section is more relevant to your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the much needed suggestions Tony.We are also trying to figure out how to go about this merger.As in shall I copy forms and subforms from my colleagues work and paste into my application and form respectively?

Comment: My advice so far has been general that would have been relevant to projects in which I was involved.  But, I have never merged two Access projects and do not feel competent to be more specific.  Perhaps someone else can help.

Comment: Hey! I found an idea somewhere on bytes.com